# About to install openSUSE on top of Ubuntu in a dual boot system with Windows 10. Do I need to remove grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, opensuse, dualboot

I am currently running a dual boot setup (Win10 & ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

I want to clean my ubuntu partitions and install openSUSE instead, do I need to get rid of grub as well or is it going to be the same one that comes with openSUSE (and can openSUSE detect that?)

Comment: A bit of a loaded question, because the answer is going to maybe, depending on a number of things, but in most cases just install any other Linux distro and use it's manual partition editor to select your Ubuntu partitions (or delete them and let the installer use remaining space) and as part of the install that distro will install grub itself, over-writing the current bootloader.